# Install on premise SharePoint 2010 Site template, on SharePoint Office365 (SP 2013 based)

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-template

Is there a setting that'll enable me to install a SharePoint 2010 site template (wsp) on SP 2013?

Answer (score 1):

You can install a site template on a SharePoint online 2013 if you subscribed to Office 365 before March 1st. Thus you should be able to import your template in a 2010 site then to upgrade the site to 2013.